# React (Next.js) cannot get click event in a custom hook to change state of parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

In React (Next.js), I'm trying to make a click event in a custom hook change the state of parent component which would then display a list below the data table, but am unable to get it because the API call and data variable are in the parent component while the click event is in the custom hook child. I've tried putting all logic from each within either file, but to no avail. Any advice appreciated!

**Component Next.js page:**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Routes from "../components/Routes";
import Table from "../components/useTable";

export const getStaticProps = async () => {
    const res = await fetch(
        "https://example.com/api/v4/...."
    );
    const data = await res.json();
    return {
        props: { data },
    };
};

const Industries = ({ data }) => {
    // Get companies, remove duplicates and sort
    const companyId = data.map((o) => o.name);
    const companies = data
        .filter(({ name }, index) => !companyId.includes(name, index + 1))
        .sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name));

    // Industry button click state
    const [industrySelected, setIndustrySelected] = useState("");

    // Get number of companies per industry
    const counted = companies.reduce((obj, v) => {
        obj[v.industryTitle] = (obj[v.industryTitle] || 0) + 1;
        return obj;
    }, {});

    // Convert object to array
    const array = Object.entries(counted);

    // Sort by descending order
    const sorted = array.sort((a, b) => b[1] - a[1]);

    return (
        <div>
            <Routes />
            <Table data={array} />
            <h2>
                <a id="list"></a>
                {industrySelected}
            </h2>
            <ol>
                {companies
                    .filter((item) => item.industryTitle === industrySelected)
                    .map((item) => (
                        <li key={item.symbol}>
                            {item.name} <u>({item.symbol})</u>
                        </li>
                    ))}
            </ol>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Industries;
```

**Custom hook useTable.js:**

```
    import React, { useState } from "react";
    
    ...

const Table = (props) => {
    const { items, requestSort, sortConfig } = useSortableData(props.data);

    // Industry button click state
    const [industrySelected, setIndustrySelected] = useState("");

    const getClassNamesFor = (name) => {
        if (!sortConfig) {
            return;
        }
        return sortConfig.key === name ? sortConfig.direction : undefined;
  };
        return (
            <div>
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        ...
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {items.map((item) => (
                            <tr key={item[0]}>
                                <td>
                                    <a
                                        href="#list"
                                        onClick={() => {
                                            setIndustrySelected(item[0]);
                                        }}
                                    >
                                        {item[0]}
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                                <td>{item[1]}</td>
                            </tr>
                        ))}
                    </tbody>
          </table>
            </div>
        );
    };
    
    export default Table;
```

Comment: your code is not clear. You seem to have a clear idea on what hook is. I advise you to read the hooks docs in react.org. understand how the data flow in react works. https://tkssharma.gitbook.io/react-training/day-01/react-js-3-principles/one-way-data-flow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to lift "up the state".

by having useState inside , when using setIndustrySelected() tou are changing only the scope of the function itself.

You need to pass setIndustrySelected as a prop instead

```
<Table data={array} setIndustrySelected={setIndustrySelected} />
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've tried adding `setIndustrySelected={setIndustrySelected}` to the table tag but am still getting the same issue. How should the onClick call in the table hook look?

Comment: Have you removed the [industrySelected, setIndustrySelected] = useState("");

from the Table component?

Also avoid <a/> tags. just use a button. href might be messing with it. 

also

onclick={() =>
     props.setIndustrySelected(item[0])
}

Comment: also you should probably use the array index while mapping :)

Comment: This is the solution. I was missing `props.` at the start of `props.setIndustrySelected(item[0])`. Thanks so much! =)

Answer (score 0):

Move `const [industrySelected, setIndustrySelected] = useState("");` to the Industries component and pass down the `setIndustrySelected` function as a prop to Table as `onIndustrySelected` and call it in the onClick instead of `setIndustrySelected(item[0]);`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've tried removing `[industrySelected, setIndustrySelected] = useState("");` from the hook and added it to the Industries component but then the hook file complains about not having access to that variable. Not sure if `onIndustrySelected` is a typo. How should the table component tag which is being passed the props look?